# Where are dunder dictionaries stored in salt?

Tags: deployment, configuration-management, configuration, salt, storage

I am new to Salt-Stack wanted to know where are all the dunder dictionaries stored?

For example `__salt__`, `__opts__`, `__grains__`, `__beacons__`).

Comment: What do you mean "stored"?

Answer (score 3):

There are currently 5 [dunder dictionaries](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/development/dunder_dictionaries.html). They are available at runtime and generally not stored statically.

`__opts__`    - Master or Minion configuration options; stored in configuration files of master and minion, collected at startup

`__salt__`    - Execution module functions (i.e. `__salt__['test.echo']('foo')`); from built-in and [custom execution modules](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/index.html) stored in `_modules/`

`__grains__`  - Grains (i.e. `__grains__['os']`); collected from minions, dynamically generated, or [stored in minion config](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/grains/#grains-in-the-minion-config) or [`/etc/salt/grains`](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/grains/#grains-in-etc-salt-grains)

`__pillar__`  - Pillar data (i.e. `__pillar__['foo']`); collected from the pillar

`__context__` - Context defined in state modules and execution modules

You generally don't need to use them, unless you are developing Salt or writing custom modules, runners, returners, or external pillars.

Comment: New doc location: https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/topics/development/modules/developing.html#dunder-dictionaries, and it now lists fifteen (though not all are available in all contexts).